# File is not `goimports`-ed with -local somePath

Tags: go

I made some changes in Golang project and later ran `make test` which takes care of linting, formatting and unit testing. But when it run linter.sh, it throws following error

```
pkg/skaffold/kubernetes/wait.go:23: File is not `goimports`-ed with -local github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold (goimports)
        "github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/pkg/skaffold/kubectl"
```

Here is the link to [Code](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/pull/3346/commits).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just doing normal `Sort imports` will probably not work. I think you have `goimports` linting with `local-prefixes` enabled, which is why the error `File is not 'goimports'-ed with -local ...`

Normally `goimports` sorts the imported libraries in a way so that standard pkg and others are in a separated group. However when you have local-prefixes enable, linting expects standard pkg, 3rd party pkg, and the pkg with the specified local-prefixes (in your case `github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold`, aka your own project pkg), these 3 types in separate group. (ref: https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/issues/209)

```golang
import (
  // stdlib

  // third-party

  // other packages of that project
)
```

> These doesn't have to be in 3 groups, you can have more that 3 groups. Just make sure that above 3 types (or 2) are not in the same one.

**Fix**

When you run `goimports` make sure you run it with `-local` flag. I think you can configure your IDE as well to do that. In your case it should look something like this:

```
goimports -local "github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold" -w .
```

> **-w** flag so that it writes the changes back
>
> **.** *(dot)* for all the files or you can specify just one file

Answer (score 22):

I hit the same error.  The lint was `golangci-lint`.

I sorted imports ( using GoLand ), tidied dependencies ( `go mod tidy` ) and removed whitespace ( `gofmt -w app.go` ).

Nothing worked apart from:

`golangci-lint run --fix`

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I had to change this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)
```

To this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)
```

Answer (score 6):

This problem usually occurs when your IDE and your linter have different settings to sort imports.
I was using *GoLand* IDE and *golangci-lint* as linter. I changed IDE settings to use ***goimports*** in place of ***gofmt*** as per the below picture and it solved these errors for me.

[image: Goland Editor Settings]

Answer (score 3):

`goimports` has an issue to sort something like this:

```
import (
    "context"

    "github.com/gofrs/uuid"

    "github.com/pkg/errors"

    "github.com/shopspring/decimal"

    "io"
)
```

It will live as it is. To make it formatted and linter-acceptable you could try this third-party to fix package imports order: https://github.com/incu6us/goimports-reviser

Example:

- before usage:

```
import (
    "log"

    "github.com/incu6us/goimports-reviser/testdata/innderpkg"

    "bytes"

    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)
```

- after usage:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "log"

    "github.com/pkg/errors"

    "github.com/incu6us/goimports-reviser/testdata/innderpkg"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I looked through your code and obviously the problem is your imports. You have to apply `goimports` command to your files to sort imports properly (or if you use Goland it can be done with IDE tools).

[image]

Info about Goland integration: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/integration-with-go-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow the 2 steps, it will work fine:-

1. Install `goimports` locally, to this run:-

> go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports@latest

2. Then for each file run:-

> goimports -w file_name.go

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes removing (portions of) comment blocks is the only fix. E.g. this was causing the problem in one file I had, and **goimports -w ...** didn't fix anything about it:

```
// Example usage:
//
//    const tracePrefix = "storage"
//
//    func FuncName(ctx context.Context, ...) {
//    fSpan, ctx := opentracing.StartSpanFromContext(ctx, CurrentFuncName(tracePrefix))
//    fSpan.SetTag("company_uuid", jwt.CompanyUUID)
//    defer fSpan.Finish()
//    ...
//    }
```

Comment: you can prefix  your comment with 
// nolint: goimports
// Example usage:

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when trying to add a JSON example in the comment

```
// newMap = {
//    "integration-algorithm" : [
//        {"container": 5},
//        {"alert-manager": 4}
//    ]
// }
```

This led to my go-lint failing.
It resolved when I removed the spacing from comment message (space between // and first alphabet).

```
 // newMap = {
 // "integration-algorithm" : [
 // {"container": 5},
 // {"alert-manager": 4}
 // ]
 // }
```

It's an excellent hack to remove these linting errors.